# nested circles in d3

Tags: d3.js

Using d3.js, how would I modify the following [code](http://jsfiddle.net/xmmqM/) to add a nested, yellow-filled circle of radius "inner_radius" to each of the existing generated circles:

```
var circleData = [
    { "cx": 300, "cy": 100, "radius": 80, "inner_radius": 40}, 
     { "cx": 75, "cy": 85, "radius": 50, "inner_radius": 20}];

var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                    .attr("width",500)
                                    .attr("height",500);

var circles = svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
                          .data(circleData)
                          .enter()
                          .append("circle");

var circleAttributes = circles
                       .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.cx; })
                       .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.cy; })
                       .attr("r", function (d) { return d.radius; })
                        .style("fill", function (d) { return "red"; });
```

Comment: I think I tried nesting circles in the past and it wasn't possible...instead I created a group (svg:g) and then appended multiple circles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As imrane said in his comment, you will want to group the circles together in a `g` svg element. You can see the updated code  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xmmqM/2/) with relevant changes below.

```
var circles = svgContainer.selectAll("g")
                          .data(circleData)
                          .enter()
                          .append("g");
// Add outer circle.
circles.append("circle")
       .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.cx; })
       .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.cy; })
       .attr("r", function (d) { return d.radius; })
       .style("fill", "red");
// Add inner circle.
circles.append("circle")
       .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.cx; })
       .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.cy; })
       .attr("r", function (d) { return d.inner_radius; })
       .style("fill", "yellow");
```